# Can't search for newly installed apps from the Windows 10 start menu

Tags: windows, windows-10

After opening the start menu, I started typing the name of an app I installed (For example Firefox). There were no results. Both normally installed and store apps won't appear in the search results. Always have to use all apps menu. How can I fix this?

Comment: Has it finished indexing the drives yet? Top of the Search says 'We are getting Search ready…' which appears to take forever...

Answer (score 0):

This has been bugging me since release and i've tried all sorts to try fix it with no success until now. I noticed on my other machines that are working 100% with search that they have the User folder included in the indexing. So I added that into my problematic PC and surprise surprise its now working, I get results on all the control panel items i didn't before and it doesn't say its getting search ready!

See [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wic94.png) for my indexing locations.

Hopefully this works for others but it may just be specific to my PC.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turned out to be cause by "Super Administrator" mode see this post [Windows 10 Start Menu search not working for new apps](https://superuser.com/questions/975271/windows-10-start-menu-search-not-working-for-new-apps)